# Trigger does not fire up when trying to update record using third party application

Tags: apex, trigger, rest, field-update

Good day, everyone I have created a trigger in salesforce and I also create a connected app to send data from my wordpress app to my custom object in salesforce. All is working well when I try to insert new record using my wordpress app. I also try to update some record in salesforce and the trigger is working well. But when I try to update some salesforce record from my wordpress, the update is successful but it seems that the trigger does fire up. What are the possible reason for this ? Below is some part of my code.

```
trigger AutoSubmit on AS_aplicant__c (after insert ,after update) {
  for (AS_aplicant__c a : trigger.new) {
         System.debug('Check if trigger is fired');
         if(Trigger.isInsert){

            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest app = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

            app.setObjectId(a.id);

            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(app);

         }
         else{
       // AS_applicant_Data__c is a Long text area and its value is JSON data.
            if( Trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).AS_applicant_Data__c != Trigger.newMap.get(a.id).AS_applicant_Data__c)
            {
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest app = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

            app.setObjectId(a.id);

            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(app);
            }
         } 

  }
}
```

Is there are any instances that a trigger does not fire up ? Or it will be disabled ? Please help

Comment: Put debug statements around your code to see if debugs are shown in logs

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I've tried to put system.debug but it didn't show up. It seems like the trigger was not read.

Comment: Can you update code with where you added debug logs

Comment: Can you verify the trigger is active?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes I can verify that my trigger is active since I've got no problem during insert.

Comment: And you're sure you actually change the value of `AS_Applicant_Data__c`?

Comment: Can you post your php code as well ?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes I am sure because the record is actually change when you compare it to the previous data.

Comment: Could it be that since the record is already in an active approval process from insert that it simply does not put it in again? Although I would think there would be an error but maybe not. Did you try canceling the pending approval before doing the update?

Comment: @Eric It is not the scenario here. Because i change the status to recalled first before doing the update. Furthermore if it is the case, salesforce will also issue an error.

Comment: Silly question, but are you tracing the correct user for your debug logs? Depending on how your Wordpress site integrates, the debug logs might be for someone other than your user. If that's the case, the insert could go through and the approval part could fail without you being able to see anything going wrong. Can you see any debug log at all?

Comment: @Aidan yes I am tracing the correct user for debug logs. but as what I've said earlier when I insert new data, I can see a debug log what when I try to update, there is no debug log. In that case I assume that the trigger is not fired up.